# Почему не отображается поле Contact form 7 с readonly?

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form7

В настройках формы плагина Contact form 7 сделал поле с readonly, после этого поле не создается на странице. Если убрать readonly поле появляется.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
[text model readonly "РП-1x42x2.0-1000" class:js-model-field]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вставить вот так:

```
[text model readonly class:js-model-field "РП-1x42x2.0-1000"]
```